# How do I skip security-constraint?

Tags: jakarta-ee, web.xml, security-constraint

I am working on an integrated solution, where we integrate multiple products under a single layer.  This layer takes care of the user authentication and acts as a single window through which I can access all the underlying products.

I am done with the single sign on (upper layer's authentication).  But, after this, each product's login page shows up.  Commenting out the 'security-constraint/login-config' from the web.xml solves the problem.  But, I should not comment it out, as the products can exist standalone even without this layer.

I would like to add a filter sort of thing which enables/disables the security-constraint based on a system property.

- When my layer authenticates(a system property can identify this), the security-constraint should be ignored.
- When my layer is not there, the security-constraint should get activated.

Any help is highly appreciated, as I have already spent a lot of time without any success on this.